# angular8 передать объект в компонент при router.navigate

Tags: frontend, angular, angular8

**UPD**
новый метод editCustomer

```js
  editCustomer(editCustomer: Customer) {
    this.router.navigate(['edit-customer'], { state: {id: editCustomer.id, name: editCustomer.name,
      address: editCustomer.address, phones: editCustomer.phones } });
  }
```

Но в компоненте в snapshot пусто

```js
export class EditCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  editCustomerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private customersClient: CustomersClient,
              private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.editCustomerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('name'), Validators.required],
      address: [this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('address'), Validators.required],
      phones: [this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('phones'), Validators.required]
    });
   }
   // остальной код
  }
```

Необходимо передать объект в компонент, для выполнения его изменения.
Хочу, чтобы объект из таблицы передавался в компонент, который отвечает за его редактирование.

Пока что сделал вот так:

**TS компонента, в который надо передать (переменная customer в ctor)**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomersClient, Customer } from 'src/app/api-service.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-customer',
  templateUrl: './edit-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-customer.component.scss']
})
export class EditCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  editCustomerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private customersClient: CustomersClient, private customer: Customer,
              private router: Router) {
    this.editCustomerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [customer.name, Validators.required],
      address: [customer.address, Validators.required],
      phones: [customer.phones, Validators.required]
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  editCustomer() {
    this.customersClient.putCustomer(this.customer.id, this.editCustomerForm.value).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('yspex');
    });
  }

  toCustomerList() {
    this.router.navigate(['list-customer']);
  }
}
```

То, как выглядит откуда хочу передавать

```js
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomersClient, Customer } from 'src/app/api-service.service';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-customer',
  templateUrl: './list-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-customer.component.scss']
})
export class ListCustomerComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  customers = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>();
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'phones', 'actions'];
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  sort: MatSort;


  constructor(private customersClient: CustomersClient, private router: Router) { }

  // ... другой код

  editCustomer(customer: Customer) {
    this.router.navigate(['edit-customer']);
  }

}
```

Собственно, как это выглядит в UI.
Задумка такая - в зависимости от того, на каком объекте пользователь нажал "Редактировать" тот объект передается в компонент, без нового запроса в БД
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [см. state](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state)

Comment: @overthesanity глянул. через this.activatedRouter.snapshot.paramMap.get('customer'); можно получать только строки. можно ли как-то передать весь объект?

Comment: Так создай объект  , заполни нужными параметрами и отправляй етот объект уже его this.router.navigate(['edit-customer'], { state: stateObj }

Comment: @Alexandr `paramMap` это сериализированные параметры URL, а не состояние.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, как работает предложенный со state вариант я не понял, поэтому сделал довольно топорно (но главное сделал)

```js
export class EditCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  editCustomerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private customersClient: CustomersClient,
              private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.editCustomerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('id'), null],
      name: [this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('name'), Validators.required],
      address: [this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('address'), Validators.required],
      phones: [this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('phones'), Validators.required]
    });
   }
   // ......
}
```

Метод, который передает параметры из ListCustomerComponent

```
  editCustomer(editCustomer: Customer) {
this.router.navigate(['edit-customer'],  { queryParams: {id: editCustomer.id, name: editCustomer.name,
  address: editCustomer.address, phones: editCustomer.phones } });
```

}